How to test React Functional component context api with enzyme
Hi I am using react functional component and I have almost covered all the test cases which works fine until I added one line if code which uses the state value from my context api provider.
MyComponent code.
The line I added
  if (uploadedSuccessfullyContext) return null;

The existing function code
const fetchUserInfo = async () => {
 const userInfo = await getUserInfo();
 setEnterpriseId(userInfo.enterpriseId);
 setFirstName(userInfo.firstName);
 setIsLoading(false)
};



 return (
    <>rest of the component jsx<>               
    )

My test cases
jest.mock("react", () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual("react"),
  useContext: jest.fn()
}));

 const mockContextValue = {
    uploadedSuccessfullyContext: false
  };

  beforeEach(() => {
    setEnterpriseIdMock = jest.fn();
    setFirstNameMock = jest.fn();
    useContext.mockReturnValue(mockContextValue);
  });

it("should get userInfo and  call axios api correctly with no data", async () => {
    let wrapper;

    const mockUserInfo = {
      enterpriseId: "mockEnterpriseId",
      firstName: "mockFirstName"
    };

    getUserInfo.mockResolvedValue(mockUserInfo);

    const mockResponse = { data: [] };
    axios.get.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve(mockResponse));

    await act(async () => {
      wrapper = mount(
        <DocumentHistory
          setEnterpriseId={setEnterpriseIdMock}
          setFirstName={setFirstNameMock}
        />
      );
    });
    expect(getUserInfo).toHaveBeenCalled();

    wrapper.update();
    expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });

The error I am getting
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')Jest
NOTE: If I remove that implementation of context api and if statement the testis passed and if add this is the error. Any idea what is missing ? your views and expertise are appreciated.

Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, can't help without seeing the code under test.
